# Spring Social Facebook Tuturial error

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social

I am trying to run [the official Spring Social](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) tutorial "as is", but I get this error. I have successfully use the same appid and secret key do login with a python application. Site url is localhost:8080. Any pointers? Any help would be appreciated.

The HelloController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Facebook facebook;

    @Inject
    public HelloController(Facebook facebook) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute(facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> homeFeed = facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", homeFeed);

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

The error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.isAuthorized(Unknown Source)
        at hello.HelloController.helloFacebook(HelloController.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post your `HelloController.java`

Comment: it crashes on the `if (!facebook.isAuthorized())`  line

Comment: From the debugger I got 
`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.toString()`

Comment: @CESCO make sure you are running JDK 1.8 or later as the example states

Comment: Can you show how you defined `Facebook` bean?

Comment: I am using JavaConfig the same as the tutorial I have not changed a single line. http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

Comment: I have filed an issue also. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/issues/176

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Facebook` bean is not available, as there is no connection yet. I slightly modified the HelloController, and I got it to work.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public HelloController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository repository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (repository.findConnections("facebook").isEmpty() || !facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<User> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendProfiles();
        model.addAttribute("friends", friends);

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

OTOH, the tutorial then asks for the deprecated read_stream permission from facebook, so you'll run into other problems afterwards. That's why my code is listing the friends instead of the the home feed.

Comment: I have been away from the Java world for a while  now but I am going to test it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Try [Spring Social Example](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social) it's `Spring 3.x` implementation, you just have to change **`Facebook/Twitter`** `apikey`, `apisecret`, `callback` url and `scope` as per your requirement in **`application.properties`** [here](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties).

Comment: I am using spring 4 and jdk 1.8. The question was already answered here [  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471698/running-imported-getting-started-project-accessing-facebook-data-appears-nullpoi ]. it a spring-boot maven dependency bug. It works with 1.2.3-RELEASE but not with 1.2.5 nor 1.2.7 with is lame because thats what my app is using. Now I am trying to findout how to overpass it.